# Is it legitimate to use analytic continuation to equate a diverging series with a finite number in a physical theory of nature?

Tags: renormalization, singularities, regularization, casimir-effect, analyticity

Analytic continuation can be used in mathematics to assign a finite value to an infinite series that diverges to infinity. Is it correct and legitimate to equate this value to a diverging infinite series that occurs in a physical theory of nature? Will this process give a correct answer that can be verified by a physics lab experiment?

A specific example: The infinite series $1+2+3+4+5+....$ occurs in a calculation for the Casimir Effect. This series is the Zeta Function at $s = -1$. $$Z(s) = 1/1^s + 1/2^s + 1/3^s + ....$$ The analytic continuation of $Z(-1)$ is $-1/12$ Is it correct to say that $$1+2+3+4+5+.... = -1/12~?$$ If you use the value $-1/12$ in your calculation of the Casimir force acting on parallel conducting plates and then measure this force in the lab, will your calculation agree with experiment?

Comment: That's the whole reason we teach it in physics classes, right? It _does_ agree with experiment. Casimir forces were measured long ago.

Comment: Terry Tao has a nice post on Zeta function regularization that may be enlightening: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/the-euler-maclaurin-formula-bernoulli-numbers-the-zeta-function-and-real-variable-analytic-continuation/

Comment: First grade teachers give kids an intuitive understanding of multiplication by physically demonstrating 5x3 by arranging 5 rows and 3 columns of cookies. The student counts the cookies and gets 15. This shows him why 5x3=15 That number wasn't just made up. I am asking for a physical or intuitive demonstration of 1+2+3+4+...= -1/12 or an intuitive explanation of why 1+1+1+1+1+...= -1/2 (It doesn't have to involve cookies) I have seen the formal mathematical proofs, but these infinite sums seem ridiculous to me. Can an infinite line of single cookies really add up to half of a negative cookie?